# How to write basic query redirects in htaccess from an asp site to wordpress

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've been attempting to write query redirects from an old version of a website using asp to new pages on a Wordpress site.    Here is an example what of what I need to have redirected:

http://www.example.com/pc/viewCategories.asp?idCategory=12

to

http://www.example.com/products/new-product/

Here is what I've tried without success:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} idCategory=12
RewriteRule ^$ /products/new-product/ [R=301,L]

I'm new to htaccess. Thank you for any direction on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're searching for IIS Redirect Module:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't apply.  We're on an apache server using htaccess now.